# Modify LINQ expression to accept IN clause

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to modify the following code line to accept a good old fashioned `IN` clause.

```
var searchResults =  (
    from s in allSites
    orderby s.SiteDescription
    where s.SiteDescription.StartsWith(siteDescription) &&
          s.SiteLocation != null
    select s);
```

I've looked at examples but not getting anywhere fast.

I'd like to add something like:

```
WHERE s.SiteStatusId IN (3,4,5)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: A simple Google search would have given you the result faster than asking here. I don't understand why people don't Google!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var ids = new [] { 3, 4, 5 };

var searchResults = from s in allSites
                    where ids.Contains(s.Id)
                    select s;
```

I *think* that does what you want, but it's been a while since I've done LINQ to SQL...

Answer (score 0):

To generate the `IN` clause, use `Contains()` on some collection.

```
var query = from s in allSites
            orderby s.SiteDescription
            where s.SiteDescription.StartsWith(siteDescription)
               && s.SiteLocation != null
               && new[] { 3, 4, 5 }.Contains(s.SiteStatusId)
            select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var siteStatusIds = new [] { 3, 4, 5 };
 var searchResults =  (
     from s in allSites
     orderby s.SiteDescription
     where s.SiteDescription.StartsWith(siteDescription) &&
           s.SiteLocation != null &&
           siteStatusIds.Contains(s.SiteStatusId)
     select s);
```